# SQL Server price table weighted to buying price

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

**Buys**

| ID | Item | qty | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 10 | 1.00 |
| 2 | 1001 | 10 | 2.00 |
| 3 | 1001 | 10 | 3.00 |
| 4 | 1002 | 10 | 2.00 |
| 5 | 1002 | 10 | 1.00 |
| 6 | 1003 | 10 | 1.00 |
| 7 | 1004 | 10 | 1.00 |
| 8 | 1004 | 10 | 2.00 |

**Fallback**

| Item | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 3.00 |
| 1002 | 3.00 |
| 1003 | 4.00 |

**Stock**

| Item | stock |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 15 |
| 1002 | 5 |
| 1003 | 25 |
| 1004 | 15 |

I have to calculate actually price each item. For that, I have to check the table "buys" each row **from the biggest ID to smallest ID** and take all prices as long as the stock is sufficient. If not enough buys in the table, I have to use the fallback prices for part of stock, I don't have price in first table.

So for item no. 1001, stock is 15. Price for 10 pcs found in ID 3 (3.00 USD); price for rest 5 pieces in row ID 2 (2.00 USD). So correct actually stockprice is 2.66 USD.

For item no. 1002, stock is 5. Price for latest buy is 1.00 USD in row ID 5 with quantity more than 5. So correct actually stockprice is 1.00 USD.

For item no. 1003, stock is 25. Only one entry in row ID 6 with 10 pcs for 1.00 USD each. so price for missing 15pcs have to take from fallback table 4.00 USD. So correct actually stockprice is 2.80 USD.

Result should be like this:

| Item | stock | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 15 | 2.66 |
| 1002 | 5 | 1.00 |
| 1003 | 25 | 2.80 |

But I have no idea how that works. Thank you very much for help.

Comment: My guess is `1001|   15|  (10*1.0+ 5*2.0)/15 = 20.0/15 = 1.33` . Are you sure?

Comment: year sure,  "... start at biggest ID...." (because it's latest buy); Items move first in where move out first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation when comparring stock to buys runnig totals, finally apply the fallback

```
select t.item, (s + t.qf * f.price) s, stock, (s + t.qf * f.price) / stock  price
from (
  select s.Item, s.Stock, 
     sum(coalesce(case when b.qe <= Stock then b.qty else Stock - b.qs end * b.price, 0)) s,
     --  qty for fallback
     min(case when Stock > coalesce(b.qe,0) then Stock - coalesce(b.qe,0) else 0 end) qf
  from Stock s
  left join (
      select Item, qty, price, ID,
        sum(qty) over(partition by Item order by ID desc) - qty qs, -- starting runnig total
        sum(qty) over(partition by Item order by ID desc) qe  -- ending runnig total
      from Buys
    ) b on s.Item = b.Item and s.Stock > b.qs
  group by s.Item, s.Stock
) t
join Fallback f on f.Item = t.Item;
order by t.Item;
```

Provided a fallback can be missing for an item a minor tweak is requierd.

```
select t.item, (s + t.qf * coalesce(f.price, 0)) s, stock, (s + t.qf * coalesce(f.price, 0)) / stock  price
from (
  select s.Item, s.Stock, 
     sum(coalesce(case when b.qe <= Stock then b.qty else Stock - b.qs end * b.price, 0)) s,
     --  qty for fallback
     min(case when Stock > coalesce(b.qe,0) then Stock - coalesce(b.qe,0) else 0 end) qf
  from Stock s
  left join (
      select Item, qty, price, ID,
        sum(qty) over(partition by Item order by ID desc) - qty qs, -- starting runnig total
        sum(qty) over(partition by Item order by ID desc) qe  -- ending runnig total
      from Buys
    ) b on s.Item = b.Item and s.Stock > b.qs
  group by s.Item, s.Stock
) t
left join Fallback f on f.Item = t.Item
where t.qf = 0 or f.item is not null
order by t.Item;
```

The query will not return a row if a fallback is required but is missing. Otherwise the row is returned.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2bb395fc359d294448d5e9708c4e5881)

Comment: There is one more error in the code. I added item no 1004 below. Buy two times and no fallback price. (Fallback not necessary as enough buys in first table). In stock are 15 pcs left of 1004. But in result, there is no 1004. Result must always same quantity like in stock.

Comment: @AlexTM1, if it's posiible that fallback is missing, then what if  the stock is greater then total Buys? For example 1004 stock is 50, buys total is qty=30, s=45, no fallback. What is the price expected?

Comment: thank you. Thats an important point. If no fallback and not enough buys or no buys, actually result (not listed in result-table) is correct. Because SQL can't calculate a correct price because of too less informations. If more buys than stock and no fallback, price should be calculated correctly in normal way.

Comment: @AlexTM1, see the sdited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a running sum of the quantity in `Buys` and calculate the price based off that.

This is somewhat complicated by the fact that you may have too many, or not enough, rows in `Buys` to fulfil the stock.

```sql
SELECT
  s.Item,
  s.stock,
  (
    ISNULL(b.FoundStockPrice, 0)
    + CASE WHEN s.stock > ISNULL(b.FoundStock, 0)
           THEN s.stock - ISNULL(b.FoundStock, 0)
           ELSE 0 END * f.price
  ) / s.stock
FROM Stock s
JOIN Fallback f ON f.Item = s.Item
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
      FoundStock = SUM(b.qty),
      FoundStockPrice = SUM(
        CASE WHEN b.FullStock > b.RunningSum THEN b.qty
          ELSE b.FullStock - (b.RunningSum - b.qty) END
        * b.price)
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          RunningSum = SUM(b.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY b.Item
                         ORDER BY b.ID DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),
          FullStock = s.stock
        FROM Buys b
        WHERE b.Item = s.Item
    ) b
    WHERE b.RunningSum - b.qty < s.stock
) b;
```

Steps are as follows:

- For every `Stock` take all relevant `Buys` rows.
- Calculate a running sum of `qty`, and then filter to only rows where the running sum *includes* the final `stock` (in other words it must up to the previous *running sum*).
- Sum these `Buys` rows multiplied by their `price`, taking into account that we need to net off anything over the necessary `stock`. Take also a total sum of the quantity.
- The final price is: the previous calculated total, plus any remaining unfound `stock` multiplied by the `fallback.price`, all divided by the total `stock`.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf885b9bf1fa4ba978a0bf8ebce789b7)

Comment: Wow, works instand! Great! I forgot a detail. Stock can be decimal (8,4). Result will be wrong in this case. Do you have a solution for this case also?

Comment: Test it with a last Buy missing.  Price is 0.

Comment: @Serg yes, you're right; thank you for the hint

Comment: @AlexTM1 Not sure what you mean. As long as the division is by a `decimal` it should all just work

Comment: @Charlieface: when you change table stock: item 1002 to 5.5 pcs, result will be 0.8181 but must be still 1.00

Comment: I think I fixed that also